# The parameter is incorrect - Error installing.NET Framework 4.6 on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, .net-4.6

I'm trying to install the .NET 4.6 Framework on a Windows Server 2012 (not R2) VM, but I keep getting the error message "The parameter is incorrect" and a link to the log file. Here is the contents of my log file:

```
OS Version = 6.2.9200, SP = 0.0, Platform 2
OS Description = Win2k12 - x64 Standard Edition
MSI = 5.0.9200.17150
Windows servicing = 6.2.9200.17280
CommandLine = C:\adcbf6016d97e2b6de93ab6a2cf0\\Setup.exe /x86 /x64 /redist
TimeZone = Pacific Daylight Time
Initial LCID = 1033
Using Simultaneous Download and Install mechanism
Operation: Installing
Package Name = Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6 Setup
Package Version = 4.6.00081
User Experience Data Collection Policy: Disabled
Number of applicable items: 6
Exe (C:\adcbf6016d97e2b6de93ab6a2cf0\SetupUtility.exe) succeeded.
Exe (C:\adcbf6016d97e2b6de93ab6a2cf0\SetupUtility.exe) succeeded.
Exe (C:\adcbf6016d97e2b6de93ab6a2cf0\x64-Windows8-RT-KB3045562-x64.cab) failed with 0x57 - The parameter is incorrect. .
Final Result: Installation failed with error code: (0x00000057), "The parameter is incorrect. " (Elapsed time: 0 00:00:22).
```

The issue seems to be associated with KB3045562, but no other details are given. Does anyone have an idea of what is wrong and how it can be fixed?

Comment: I found same issue on Same issue for the 4.6.1 Framework.